# Not able to play .avi files with VLC media player on Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry pi2

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, codecs

What to do if I can't play a .avi file with VLC media player? (the only video software installed on Ubuntu mate).
The window is automatically closed.
I'm not able to play any other .avi files.

fresh installation of Ubuntu mate on raspberry pi 2

Comment: Ubuntu for ARM is not meant to play videos due to lack of support for the graphics drivers.

Comment: @MichaelBay: What? Why? Since when? Are you sure that applies to all video codecs? How do you know which video codec the file contains?

Comment: Can you play the video in other media players, e. g. Totem? Can you play other video formats? Also, could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `ffprobe VIDEOFILE.avi` so we can see the media codec(s) in use. Alternatively a link to a sample video will do. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Most ARM CPUs and companion graphics have closed source that typically is licensed for Android only. Some vendor release source code, most don't. Granted, I don't know the exact situation with the Pis but almost all the other dev boards and miniPC/media players have video issues (with a desktop Linux distro) of one type or another. Sometimes graphics drivers can be installed but most users run the images "as is". The "fresh installation" and no mention of installing drivers suggests that is the case. But I can be wrong, I know little about ARM.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

Comment: @MichaelBay: Most media players and certainly VLC have software decoders for all their supported video codecs. Of course if the media player tries to use hardware acceleration that the driver advertises and there's a bug in the somewhere in the pipeline the application may crash.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have proper codecs installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

**Hardware accelerated video with VLC and ffmpeg**
Ubuntu MATE 16.04 added OpemMAX IL hardware accelerated video playback to VLC and MMAL hardware accelerated video playback to `ffmpeg`.

To enable hardware accelerated video playback in VLC go to **Tools** -> **Preferences** -> **Video** and select **OpenMax IL**.
To use hardware accelerated video playback with ffplay you must specify the **h264_mmal** codec.

```
ffplay -vcodec h264_mmal video.mp4
```

Hardware accelerated playback on the Raspberry Pi works by overlaying the video directly to the screen. Therefore there are no onscreen controls for playback control. You’ll need to use the VLC and ffmpeg keyboard shortcuts.

> SOURCE: https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/

Also some people recommends to use `omxplayer` for accelerated video playback on Raspberry pi x.

Comment: @Nadavt Cool, If the answer helped check it as SOLVED/ANSWERED  thx